# Calling methods through XMLRPC - Odoo v9

Tags: php, mysql, odoo, odoo-9

I have a simple function on a custom model to create a record from info passed by xmlrpc (PHP with ripcord library) but when I execute the php the odoo console returns the following error:

> "cannot marshal recursive dictionaries" TypeError: cannot marshal
> recursive dictionaries "

The data who I'm passing are a "Json" stored in a text field in a database, so first I resolve the query and get the data from DB and then try to send it to Odoo through XMLRPC

Here's my code:

t_form_main model

```
class t_form_main(models.Model):
        _name       =   "t_form_main"   
        _rec_name   =   "form_uid"
        _order      =   "form_uid"
        form_uid    =   fields.Char(string="ID",required=True)
        json_string =   fields.Text(string="JSON_original", required=True)

@api.one
        def infoReceptor(self,info_uid,json_data):
            vals                =   {}
            vals['form_uid']    =   info_uid
            vals['json_string'] =   json_data
            return super(t_form_main,self).create(vals)
```

The php sentence who I'm using to invoke XMLRPC:

```
  $insert =   $models->execute_kw($db, $uid, $password,'t_form_main','infoReceptor', array(self,"UID",$data));
```

considering $data as the variable who stores the data from this query:

```
$query      =   "SELECT raw_json FROM json_archive";
$result     =   $mysqlconn->query($query);
$row        =   $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

---

#### Solution

The code was right, the problem was caused by a issue in the DB codification, thanks to Phillip Stack for your advice in the return of my function.

Answer (score 0):

When returning a response of a create function you need to decorate your create function for the model with @api.returns with a lambda function returning the record id for you newly created record. In your case if you do not want to do that I would add `.id` to the end of your return line.

```
return super(t_form_main,self).create(vals).id
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that just improve the output for the return. I've solved my problem, was a codification issue on the DB